# C# comparing two object values

Tags: c#

I have 2 List objects.

```
private static List<Logs> _logsDutyStatusChange = new List<Logs>();
private static List<Logs> _logsNonDutyStatusChange = new List<Logs>();
```

Both of these lists contain a driverid and a date.

I need to see which driverid's are in `_logsNonDutyStatusChange` that are also in `_logsDutyStatusChange`.

If they are in `_logsNonDutyStatusChange`, then replace the date in `_logsDutyStatusChange` with the MaxDate in `_logsNonDutyStatusChange`.

How would I go about this. Right now I have the following(does not work):

```
 foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
            {
                if (_logsNonDutyStatusChange.Contains(log.did))
                {

                }

            }
```

Comment: What is your approach? share what you've already done? and where exactly you need help?

Comment: I have populated the list objects through web service calls using linq. I need help with comparing the data between the 2 objects then populating the _logsDutyStatusChange with the other objects data if the driver id exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use Linq:

```
var lookup = _logsNonDutyStatusChange.ToLookup(l => l.did);

foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
{
    if (lookup.Contains(log.did))
    {
        var maxDate = lookup[log.did].Max(l => l.date);
        log.date = maxDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could implement `IEquatable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this **if you want to do it purely the Linq way**

```
  _logsDutyStatusChange.Where(x=> _logsNonDutyStatusChange.Any(y=>y.DriveId == x.DriveId))
            .ToList().ForEach(xx => xx.Date = _logsNonDutyStatusChange.Where(yy=>yy.DriveId==xx.DriveId)
            .Max(yyy=>yyy.Date));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use for-loops, you need this:

```
foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
{
    foreach (var nonDutyLog in _logsNonDutyStatusChange)
    {
        if (nonDutyLog.did.Equals(log.did))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

But note that this is O(n*m), which is expensive, particularly if you have a lot of entries. If you need something like this, you'll be better of converting some of these lookups into hash tables. The quick and easy way to do this is with `ToLookup()`:

```
var nonDutyLookup = _logsNonDutyStatusChange.ToLookup(log => log.did, log => log);

foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
{
    foreach (matchingLog in nonDutyLookup[log.did])
    {
        // handle the matching log
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
 {


    if (_logsNonDutyStatusChange.Select (l => l.did).Contains(log.did))
    {

    }

 }
```